# How do I write a function in DrRacket ISL/Lambda that moves occurrences of certain items to the end of the list?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to learn how to do this, and I know it involves stacks, but I can't wrap my head around it unless I see a function in action. We've been given this example of a function to create and I need some help. Here it is:

```
;leafpile takes a   list    and returns the result  of  pushing all 
;occurrences    of  the symbol  'leaf   to  the end of  the list

> (leafpile '(rock grass leaf leaf acorn leaf))
(list 'rock 'grass 'acorn 'leaf 'leaf 'leaf)
```

We can use a helper function but the function needs to be written in a way to minimize recursive passes

update (heres what I got so far)

```
(define (leafpile/help ls pile)
 (local
    [
     (define (helper 2ls leafpile)
  (cond
    [(empty? 2ls) (filter ls 'leaf)]
    [(equal? (first 2ls) 'leaf)
     (cons (first 2ls) (helper (rest 2ls) leafpile))]
    [else (helper (rest 2ls) leafpile)]))]
    (helper ls pile)))
```

OK snow I have this:

```
(define (helper lsh)
  (cond
    [(empty? lsh) '()]
    [(not(equal? (first lsh) 'leaf))
     (cons (first lsh) (helper (rest lsh)))]
    [else (helper (rest lsh))]))

(define (count-leaf ls)
  (cond
    [(empty? ls) 0]
    [(not (equal? 'leaf (first ls))) (count-leaf (rest ls))]
    [else (add1 (count-leaf (rest ls)))]))

(define (leafpile ls)
  (append (helper ls) (make-list (count-leaf ls) 'leaf)))
```

but I need it in one simple function with the least recursive passes possible.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. This appears to be a homework problem. Homework questions are not necessarily off-topic on Stack Overflow, but we require a minimal demonstration that you have *attempted to solve the question yourself* so that we can help guide you in the right direction. Please post what you’ve tried so far and where you are stuck—we won’t do your homework for you.

Comment: I have the helper I was trying to implement but I got an error. This is not a homework problem. We were actually given it as a challenge in lecture but I can't figure out the rest.

Comment: You don't need a stack. Just have a variable in your helper that counts the number of `leaf` you skip and use `(make-list n 'leaf)` as the tail. The easiest is using your idea to use `filter` by appending the results of using `filter` twice with one predicate that are true for every non leaf and the other for every leaf. Not very fancy but ok for small lists. Why optimize?

Comment: Sylwester can you pretty please write that in code?

Comment: I take it the counting number of  'leaf' I skip is an "accumulator," right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
(define (leafpile lst)
  (for/fold ([pile (filter (lambda (leaf?) (not (equal? leaf? 'leaf))) lst)])
            ([i (build-list (for/fold ([leaves 0])
                                      ([leaf? lst])
                              (if (equal? leaf? 'leaf)
                                  (add1 leaves)
                                  leaves)) values)])
    (append pile '(leaf))))
```

How it works:
The main `for/fold` loop iterates over a list with a length of the number of leaves there are, and the 'collection value' is a list of all the elements in `lst` that aren't the symbol `'leaf` (achieved by `filter`).
Sample input/output:

> > (leaf-pile '(rock grass leaf leaf acorn leaf))
>   '(rock grass acorn leaf leaf leaf)

Answer (score 0):

Really simple way to do this:

```
(define (leaf? v) 
  (eq? v 'leaf)) 

(define (leafpile lst)      
  (append (filter (compose not leaf?) lst)
          (filter leaf? lst)))
```

It really doesn't need to be more to it unless you experience performance issues and I usually don't for small lists. I tend to think of lists with fewer than a million elements as small. The obvious recursive one that might not be faster:

```
(define (leafpile lst)
  (local [(define (leafpile lst n) ; screaming for a named let here!
          (cond
            ((null? lst) (make-list n 'leaf))
            ((leaf? (car lst)) (leafpile (cdr lst) (add1 n)))
            (else (cons (car lst) (leafpile (cdr lst) n)))))]
    (leafpile lst 0)))
```

A tail recursive one that accumulates non leaf values, counts leaf values and uses srfi/1 `append-reverse!` to produce the end result:

```
(require srfi/1)

(define (leafpile lst)
  (local [(define (leafpile lst acc n) ; I'm still screaming 
        (cond
          ((null? lst) (append-reverse! acc (make-list n 'leaf)))
          ((leaf? (car lst)) (leafpile (cdr lst) acc (add1 n)))
          (else (leafpile (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc) n))))]
    (leafpile lst '() 0)))
```